# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln (n)}$ WITHOUT using the integral test.

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Yesterday I was tutoring a high school student on the convergence of infinite series. We encounter the following series on his practice assignment:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln (n)}$$

He's at the precalculus level so he hasn't seen the integral test which would be the standard method for determining that this particular series diverges.
His teacher though gave him a hint that the formula for infinite interest compound was to be used. I assumed that we had to use something along the lines of:

$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( 1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\implies x=\lim_{n\to\infty} n \ln \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)$$

I couldn't do it in the end, it takes me to weird places. Is there really a way of determining this series is divergent without using the integral test?

Edit: The tests that the teacher taught my student and thus the only ones allowed are the following:
nth term test, Comparison/limit comparison test, alternating series test, ratio test.

Comment: The Cauchy condensation test works too, but it doesn't look like this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Excatly the tests that I was allowed to use with the student wee comparison, limit comparison, ratio, nth term, alternating.

Comment: Similar problem: [Show the series diverges using only comparison test](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3580462/272831)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the hint you had: notice that
$$\ln\ln(n+1) - \ln\ln n = \ln\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}
= \ln\left( 1+ \frac{\ln(1+1/n)}{\ln n} \right)$$
Now, the series 
$$
\sum_{n=2}^N (\ln\ln(n+1) - \ln\ln n)
$$
is telescopic and diverges. And by the limit comparison test, the two series
$$
\sum_n \ln\left( 1+ \frac{\ln(1+1/n)}{\ln n}\right), \qquad \sum_n \frac{1}{n\ln n}
$$
have same behavior since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left( 1+ \frac{\ln(1+1/n)}{\ln n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n\ln n}} = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Replace $\ln$ by $\log$ base 2, larger than
$$  \frac{1}{2 \cdot 1} + $$
$$  \frac{1}{3 \cdot 2} +   \frac{1}{4 \cdot 2} +  $$
$$  \frac{1}{5 \cdot 3} +   \frac{1}{6 \cdot 3} +   \frac{1}{7 \cdot 3} +   \frac{1}{8 \cdot 3} + $$
$$  \frac{1}{9 \cdot 4} +   \frac{1}{10 \cdot 4} +   \frac{1}{11 \cdot 4} +   \frac{1}{12 \cdot 4} +\frac{1}{13 \cdot 4} +   \frac{1}{14 \cdot 4} +   \frac{1}{15 \cdot 4} +   \frac{1}{16 \cdot 4} + $$
$$  \frac{1}{17 \cdot 5} +   \frac{1}{18 \cdot 5} +   \frac{1}{19 \cdot 5} +   \frac{1}{20 \cdot 5} +\frac{1}{21 \cdot 5} +   \frac{1}{22 \cdot 5} +   \frac{1}{23 \cdot 5} +   \frac{1}{24 \cdot 5} +  \frac{1}{25 \cdot 5} +   \frac{1}{26 \cdot 5} +   \frac{1}{27 \cdot 5} +   \frac{1}{28 \cdot 5} +\frac{1}{29 \cdot 5} +   \frac{1}{30 \cdot 5} +   \frac{1}{31 \cdot 5} +   \frac{1}{32 \cdot 5} +$$

---

This is bigger than
$$  \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{8} +  \frac{4}{24} + \frac{8}{64} + \frac{16}{160} + \dots$$
or
$$   \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} +  \frac{1}{6} +   \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{10} +  \dots$$

Comment: Isn't that essentially the Cauchy Condensation test, unrolled?

Comment: @ClementC. I wouldn't know. I will probably look it up; meanwhile, this format is suitable for a pre-calc student

Comment: It is, and I'm glad seeing that this works, unfortunately this test wasn't taught by the teacher. I'm gonna edit my question to post only the convergence tests that were allowed.

Comment: @MarkA.Ruiz As Will mentions, you can use this without knowing the Cauchy condensation test, as a "very clever (self-contained) trick" (and then maybe even use it to actually introduce/motivate said condensation test).

Comment: @MarkA.Ruiz  I think you are missing a bet here... I had never heard of Cauchy condensation, never taught it. This is just an explicit divergent series which is exceed by the original sum. No need to call it a test, except that it is a comparison.

Comment: @ClementC. thank you. Another aspect is that I'm not saying, and the student need not be informed, that a variation of this could be constructed to show convergence for $1/(n \log^2 n).$ So it seems fair to omit the word "test" for the moment.

Answer (score 3):

A variation on @ClementC's insight uses just the inequality $\ln(1+x)\le x$:
$$
\frac1{n\ln n}\ge\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)}{\ln n}\ge\ln\left(1+\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)}{\ln n}\right).
$$
The RHS leads to a telescoping sum, so the series in question diverges by comparison.