# Show the series diverges using only comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+4)\ln(n+4)\ln(\ln(n+4))}$$

I need to prove the divergence of this series using only comparison test but I don't see a proper comparison.
Have no idea how to do this

Comment: Can you find a smaller, simpler function to compare it to that diverges as well?

Comment: This is the main problem. I can't find it

Comment: *Only* is a big word here and needs to be interpreted sensibly.   But as a hint, you might want to look at the derivative of $\ln(\ln(\ln(x+4)))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift the terms over so that this is easier to work with:

$$S=\sum_{n\ge3}\frac1{n\ln(n)\ln(\ln(n))}$$

We can see that $\ln(x)\le\log_2(x)$ for $x\ge1$, which means $1/\ln(x)\ge1/\log_2(x)$, allowing us to compare this against:

$$S\ge\sum_{n\ge3}\frac1{n\log_2(n)\log_2(\log_2(n))}$$

At this point we apply [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test). The key is noting that the summand is decreasing so that replacing $n$ with something larger, namely the next power of 2, will result in less. Visually, this is what we are doing:

\begin{align}S&\ge\color{blue}{\frac1{3\log_2(3)\log_2(\log_2(3))}+\frac1{4\log_2(4)\log_2(\log_2(4))}}\\{}\\&\color{magenta}{\hspace{1pt}{}+\frac1{5\log_2(5)\log_2(\log_2(5))}+\frac1{6\log_2(6)\log_2(\log_2(6))}}\\&\color{magenta}{\hspace{1pt}{}+\frac1{7\log_2(7)\log_2(\log_2(7))}+\frac1{8\log_2(8)\log_2(\log_2(8))}}\\{}\\&\hspace{1pt}{}+\dots\\{}\\{}\\&\ge\color{blue}{\frac1{4\log_2(4)\log_2(\log_2(4))}+\frac1{4\log_2(4)\log_2(\log_2(4))}}\\{}\\&\color{magenta}{\hspace{1pt}{}+\frac1{8\log_2(8)\log_2(\log_2(8))}+\frac1{8\log_2(8)\log_2(\log_2(8))}}\\&\color{magenta}{\hspace{1pt}{}+\frac1{8\log_2(8)\log_2(\log_2(8))}+\frac1{8\log_2(8)\log_2(\log_2(8))}}\\{}\\&\hspace{1pt}+\dots\\{}\\{}\\&=\color{blue}{\frac2{4\log_2(4)\log_2(\log_2(4))}}+\color{magenta}{\frac4{8\log_2(8)\log_2(\log_2(8))}}+\dots\\&=\color{blue}{\frac1{2\cdot2\log_2(2)}}+\color{magenta}{\frac1{2\cdot3\log_2(3)}}+\dots\end{align}

$$S\ge\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{2n\log_2(n)}$$

Repeating this process once more will give us

$$S\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{4n}$$

and because why not, we can do it again:

$$S\ge\frac14+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac18$$

Comment: OMG You are a genius! This is a brilliant idea! Thank you